# How to get the job id of a specific running hadoop jobs

Tags: hadoop

I need to get the id of a specific hadoop job. 
In my case, I lunch a sqoop commande remotely and I went to verify the job status with this commande :

```
hadoop job -status job_id | grep -w 'state'
```

I can get this information from the GUI but i went to do something 
can any one help me !!!

Comment: I see this question, i don't use the java code. her I lunch a **sqoop** commande with ssh and i went to get the id of this job
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Yarn REST apis, via your browser or curl from the command line. It will list all the currently running and previously running jobs, including sqoop and the mapreduce jobs that sqoop generates and executes. Use the UI first, if you have it up and running just point your browser to `http:<host>:8088/cluster` (not sure if the port is the same on all hadoop distributions. I believe 8088 is the default on apache). Alternatively you can use yarn commands directly, e.g, `yarn application -list`.

Comment: Thanks for your resonse, but i went to get the id of the job created by my **sqoop** command not all job in yarn

Comment: the job created by your sqoop command is one of the jobs in yarn (sqoop internally runs a mapreduce job). You'll have to look at the list and find it. Since you don't provide any input parameter there's no way to point to any specific job. I may be misunderstanding your intention.